# Symmetric Encryption isn't working

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to generate cipher text and decrypted data. I already have assigned my incrypted value and key. But when I run the program in netbeans it shows error in the execution area, but no cipher text and decrypted data is produced.

Encryption.java:

```
package encryption;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryption {

    private static byte[] message;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        byte[] message = {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 8, 9};
        byte[] key = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};
        byte[] ciphertext;
        byte[] decrypted;

        Sender s = new Sender();
        s.send(message);
        Receiver r = new Receiver();
        r.receive(message);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Sender.java:

```
package encryption;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Sender {

    private Cipher encoder;
    private SecretKeySpec myKey;

    public Sender() throws Exception {
       encoder = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    }

    public void setKey(byte[] key) throws Exception {
      myKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        encoder.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);
    }

    public byte[] send(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        return encoder.doFinal(message);
    }
}
```

Receiver.java:

```
package encryption;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Receiver {
    private Cipher decoder;
    private SecretKeySpec myKey;
    public Receiver()throws Exception{

        decoder=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    }
    public void setKey(byte[] key) throws Exception{

        myKey= new SecretKeySpec(key ,"AES");
        decoder.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey);
    }
    public byte[] receive(byte[] message) throws Exception{
        return decoder.doFinal(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: "it shows error"? Is that all you can share with us?

Comment: Hint: Use the return value from `s.send(message);` call.

Comment: marko topolnik, the error is following: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCipherState(Cipher.java:1672)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2079)
 at encryption.Sender.send(Sender.java:22)
 at encryption.Encryption.main(Encryption.java:23)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Isn't the error message telling you what is wrong? It tells you that the cipher is not initialized. So, have you called init() on the cipher before using it? No, you haven't.

Comment: I don't see any IV handling